# bootstrap vue input on a modal autofocus

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

i have a bootstrap-vue input on a modal

```
<b-form-input  id="inputText1" ref="inputText1" v-model="inputText" autofocus></b-form-input>
```

the modal is a bootstrap-vue modal and the show/hide is controlled by a v-if directive.

When the modal is opened the input has focus. If i close the modal the input doesn't have focus anymore.

I have tried to set the autofocus property each time the modal is mounted but it still doesn't focus. I have tried using $nextTick also.

Comment: The `autofocus` prop on `b-form-input` (and `-select` and others) only works when the form control is mounted.

If your modal is set to `static` mode (without the `lazy` option), the input will be mounted but invisible/hidden.  Autofocus will not work in this situation.  The modal needs to have the `lazy` prop set if `static`, or the modal needs to not be static.

Comment: Note the speial `autofocus` prop/functionality was added in BootstrapVue `v2.0.0-rc.21`. Make sure you are using the latest version.

Comment: Yes, autofocus works. I Guess my idea was just wrong, I think if the user clicks edit, sees inputs and the first of them is focused, then it should be clear enough he can edit the input fields. My bad. Thanks to anyone. Should I just delete this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recomend to you use `v-model` with vue bootstrap modal

**template**

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <b-button @click="showModal= !showModal">Open your bmodal</b-button>
        <b-modal v-model="showModal">Yor modal is active!</b-modal>
        <b-form-input  id="inputText1" ref="inputText1" v-model="inputText" autofocus></b-form-input>

      </div>
    </template>
```

**vue code**

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
       data() {
      return {
        showModal: false
      }
    },
  watch:{
    showModal:function(value){
     // set the focus when the modal opened/closed
      this.$refs.inputText1.focus();
    }
  },
      mounted(){
        // set the focus when the component opened
         this.$refs.inputText1.focus();
      },
      methods: {

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to listen to the modal event `shown`:

`<b-modal @shown="$refs.inputText1.focus()"></b-modal>`

Unlike other elements where you can use created or mounted to reliably focus, modals require a different approach because they get inserted into the body and the hooks don't fire as others do.